# Rate limiting on NGINX

Tags: nginx

We are using NGINX as a proxy server+load balancer for other servers on the same network that use Apache.

For security, we want to apply a rate limiting per IP, so that if there are more than 100 requests in a second, or even more than 100 requests for the same page in a short period of time, the source IP will be blocked for a while.

Another idea we had was if the IP triggers more than 100 requests in which all of them returned a 404, 403 or 500 code in a small amount of time, the IP would also be blocked.

Using Apache logs + fail2ban and mod_evasive, we were able to do something very similar.
But with Nginx we couldn't, we tried to apply a basic rule of rate limit, but before reaching the limit we already have blocking errors.

We use the settings below to configure this block when the user reaches the limit.

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=200r/s;
limit_req zone=one burst=20;
```

It so happens that even if a user makes 97 AJAX requests on the first access, Nginx blocks these requests, as shown in the log below:

```
2022/07/19 11:10:37 [error] 8494#8494: *1698 limiting requests, excess: 20.600 by zone "one", client: [USER-IP], server: example.com, request: "GET /views/components/page-1.html HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/dash.html"
2022/07/19 11:10:37 [error] 8495#8495: *1699 limiting requests, excess: 20.600 by zone "one", client: [USER-IP], server: example.com, request: "GET /views/components/page-2.html HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/dash.html"
2022/07/19 11:10:37 [error] 8495#8495: *1702 limiting requests, excess: 20.800 by zone "one", client: [USER-IP], server: example.com, request: "GET /views/components/page-3.html HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/dash.html"
```

How can we make these settings on our NGINX server?

Comment: I did not get the point. you already using the limitations?

Comment: @djdomi I tried to do a basic configuration but it didn't work, nginx started blocking access before reaching the limit.
I think I didn't do it right, so my post was to ask how to do exactly these settings correctly.

Comment: Tom, consider the [origin post](https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/) of the vendor of NGINX. they explain how it works.

Comment: Thank you very much @djdomi, this article is very different from what I had found and has more information.

Comment: so basically imho you set it already wrong ;)